# From list of dict to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, real-time

I'm retrieving real-time financial data. 
Every 1 second, I pull the following list:

> [{'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 'price': '0.03381600'}, {'symbol': 'LTCBTC', 'price': >'0.01848300'}...]

The goal is to put this list into an already-existing pandas DataFrame.

What I've done so far is converting this list of a dictionary to a pandas DataFrame. My problem is that symbols and prices are in two columns. I would like to have symbols as the DataFrame header and add a new row every 1 second containing price's values.

```
marketInformation = [{'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 'price': '0.03381600'}, {'symbol': 'LTCBTC', 'price': >'0.01848300'}...]

data = pd.DataFrame(marketInformation)
header = data['symbol'].values

newData = pd.DataFrame(columns=header)

while True:
  realTimeData = ... // get a new marketInformation list of dict
  newData.append(pd.DataFrame(realTimeData)['price'])

print(newData)
```

Unfortunately, the printed DataFrame is always empty. I would like to have a new row added every second with new prices for each symbol with the current time. 
I printed the below part:

```
pd.DataFrame(realTimeData)['price']
```

and it gives me a pandas.core.series.Series object with a length equals to the number of symbol.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After you create `newData`, just do:

```py
newData.loc[len(newData), :] = [item['price'] for item in realTimeData]
```

Comment: The header length is around 500 symbols. I’m afraid looping every second will be very slow.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `set_index()` and then transpose the df:

```
newData = pd.DataFrame(marketInformation).set_index('symbol').T                                                           

#In [245]: newData                                                                                                                   
#Out[245]: 
#symbol      ETHBTC         LTC
#price   0.03381600  0.01848300

# then change the index to whatever makes sense to your data
newdata_time = pd.Timestamp.now()
newData.rename(index={'price':newdata_time})
#Out[246]: 
#symbol                          ETHBTC         LTC
#2019-04-03 17:08:51.389359  0.03381600  0.01848300
```